# SQL assigning a value after testing against multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns:

INPUT

```
col1 col2
1    0
1    0
1    0
2    1
2    0
3    0
3    0
3    1
3    1
```

Let's suppose col1 holds some entity ID number, which is repeated. I'm testing whether this entity ID contains value 1 in col2. So if entity ID has 1 in corresponding col2 then I create another col3 with "NO"/"YES" values or just "0"/"1" accrodingly.

OUTPUT

```
col1 col3
1    NO
2    YES
3    YES
```

Comment: what do you mean you create a column? Does this column already exist in your ddl?

Comment: no, col3 does not exist. It is created with appropriate value AFTER I run through table with col1, col2

Comment: do you want a SELECT or an UPDATE statement?

Comment: I don't think I can judge. I'd go with SELECT since it is more common I guess

Comment: But, don't you know what you need? you want to sell a car or to buy a car?

Comment: haha you're funny :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Col1, MAX(CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Col3
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Col1
```

**UPDATED**
Well, since the query above doesn't work for you, you can try the following:

```
SELECT Col1, MAX(Col3) Col3
FROM (  SELECT  Col1, 
                CASE WHEN col2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Col3
        FROM YourTable) A
GROUP BY Col1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
    col3 = DECODE(col2, 1, 'YES', 'NO');
```

If you want to run this for a given entity id only:

```
UPDATE table 
SET 
    col3 = DECODE(col2, 1, 'YES', 'NO')
WHERE
    col1 = yourid;
```

If your column 3 does not exist, you'll have to create it *before hand* anyway:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD (col3 NUMBER NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Col1,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Col2) = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS Col3
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Col1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54bce/3)

Comment: This assumes that the only available values for `col2` are 0 or 1 (it works for the sample data, but is not specified)

Comment: @Lamak yes, and the basis of the assumption is the record provided by the OP itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyTab WHERE col1 = M.col1 AND col2 = 1) 
THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' AS col3 FROM MyTab M
```